# C# Cell LiteralControl Get Text Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

How come this doesn't work for getting the text value of a literalcontrol on export of a gridview to Excel?

```
cell.Text = (cell.Controls[0] as LiteralControl).Text;
```

Edit: (Complete Code)

```
                    if (cell.HasControls())
                {

                    switch (cell.Controls[0].GetType().Name)
                    {
                        case "HyperLink":
                    cell.Text = (cell.Controls[0] as HyperLink).Text;
                    cell.Controls.Clear();
                    cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
                    break;
                        case "LinkButton":
                    cell.Text = (cell.Controls[0] as LinkButton).Text;
                    cell.Controls.Clear();
                    cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
                    break;
                        case "LiteralControl":
                    cell.Text = (cell.Controls[0] as LiteralControl).Text;
                    cell.Controls.Clear();
                    cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
                    break;
                    }

                    //cell.Text = cell.Controls[0].GetType().Name;


                }
```

Comment: I ran the export and added what type of control is in the cells. Hyperlinks work and I'm able to get the text and strip out the control. Cells with LiteralControls can't read the controls text.

Comment: add more appropriate tags. seems like asp.net question

Comment: What is happening are you getting literal control as null or Text property is an empty string? Are you sure cell.Controls[0] is literal control? Have you checked it by inspecting its type?

Comment: It's an empty string. It knows it's a LiteralControl but the text doesn't get read.

Comment: Edited and add complete code. The hyperlinks and LinkButton text gets read.

Comment: can you post the code where you are setting value to your literal control?

Comment: I'm using the C# code just like it is here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: It seems you have used controls within gridview, instead of just bound fields, I need to see what controls you have used with gridview and how you are assigning value to those controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net adds LiteralControl by default in gridview template field for spacing or whatever reason, so you are referring that control instead of yours, try using

```
cell.Controls[1]
```

instead of

```
cell.Controls[0]
```

in case of LiteralControl.

Also if possible you can assign ID to controls and use those ID, in that case this problem of referring incorrect element will not surface as you will refer control with its specific ID.

Comment: This worked:                             case "LiteralControl":
                        cell.Text = (cell.Controls[1] as HyperLink).Text;
                        cell.Controls.Clear();
                        break;

Answer (score 0):

((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal)agentGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[1]).Text

Comment: Please provide more context to you answer and explain how it solves the issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34992251)